# Dynamic Data Entities Web Application Handle delete statement conflicted

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've created an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application project with visual studio 2010.
I've added a ADO.NET Entity Data Model connected to a sql Server database.

The application works fine.

I'd like to handle an exception when deleting a row in a table that has a column which is a foreign key for another table.

The exception is :

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_name". The conflict 
>   occurred in database "NAME", table "dbo.dbname", column 'Column_name'.

What I'd like to do is display a user friendly message to explain that the operation cannot be made before other rows in other table are delete.

I did some step by step debugging, but I can't find where the application does the database request, so that I can customize the code.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post more information in order for us to help. What does your application code look like when someone clicks delete?

Comment: You may want to consider enabling cascading deletes on your models rather than taking the effort to pop the error message up on deletes. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx.

Comment: @CharlieBrown the OP stated that they were using dynamic data, thus the code behind the delete function is autogenerated by the framework.

Comment: @JimWooley Thanks, reading the article I'd like to do the opposite : prevent cascading on both sql server and entities. I've tired adding <OnDelete Action="None" /> attribute to my foreign key on xml view of edmx file, but with no changes on delete behaviour, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and i found two options :
- I can handle the delete directly with gridview attribute `OnRowDeleting`. This mean a lot of entity manipulation
- I can handle entity framework SavingChanges and check for entities on `EntityState.Deleted`, then check entity navigation properties and throw an explicit message if necessary. This works with a custom validation error to show user friendly message.

Comment: would have been nice to have some code examples on this.  I need to do the same thing